# Suitable where clause in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

### Background

A table with the following columns and data such as:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Address | AddressLine2 | AddressLine3 | Locality | District | State | Country |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Sector-12|              |              |          | Faridabad| Har   | IN      |
| 311     |              |              |  Sector 3| Faridabad| Har   | IN      |
|Sector-1,|              |              |          | Faridabad| Har   | IN      |
|Plot 31  |              |              | Old Fari | Faridabad| Har   | IN      |
|         |              |              |dabad     |          |       |         |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What I am trying to depict here is that the data in Address, AddressLine2, AddressLine 3, Locality can be absolutely random.

### Requirement

Detect current location and find nearby schools in the database with above columns in the school table.

### Process

Nearby schools are located using the Google API which returns the names of the schools along with their address.

E.g. returned data:

```
Name: St. Albans School
Address: Sector 1, Old Faridabad, Faridabad, Har, IN
```

Expected result:
School with Address `Sector-1` and Locality as `Old Faridabad`

---

District, State and Country are automatically taken using the current location.

In order to process the rest of the address what is currently taking place is the school address exploded based on `,` and a mysql query is produced which uses `IN`.

Example query:

```
Select * from Schools where Address IN ('Sector-1', 'Sector 1', Sector- 1'. 'Old Faridabad', ...)
```

However a **problem** with `IN query` is:
- If the address column contains a string such as `"Sector-1,"`, the match with fail.

Another approach:

```
Select * from Schools where Address REGEX "Sector-1|Sector 1|Sector- 1|Old Faridabad|..."
```

Problem with this approach, if a school address is like: 314, Sector 19, Faridabad. Splitting the string based on `,` results in a search criteria of `314` in the query. Hence a school with address: 314, Sector 31, Faridabad will also result in a match though these schools are far away from each other.

Any suggestions on how to write a mysql query which helps in selecting the correct schools.

NOTE: Address can also contain text like: `"314, Sector 19"` together.

Comment: why not just select the sectors in the IN()?? `where Address IN(SELECT address from Schools)`

Comment: I don't think you should split by ','. Google API geoloc service returns more than just the address, but also the area, region, etc. Furthermore, you should leave to Google Maps API to calculate the distance between the school queried and the other schools : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix

Comment: @Bonatoc - Its important that I rely on the database provided here as it has further use to the application.

Comment: In case you wonder why I suggest you to rely entirely upon Google Maps API DistanceMatrix, it's because a school can be on a border of a sector, and can have a school nearby in the adjacent sector, so searching within the same sector is useless. It all depends what you mean by "nearby".

Comment: @Namit - Still, you could store more data from Google Maps in your SQL table, query Google asynchronously for distances, and store them in your DB.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just need to check for the leading and trailing comma:

```
REGEX "(^|, )(Sector-1|Sector 1|Sector- 1|Old Faridabad|...)(,|$)"
```